# Using a completion block from Swift Framework in Objective C crashes on Release

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I'm writing code in Objective C and I'm using a framework that's written in Swift. In the code, there's a function I'm calling that has a completion block in it's declatation, the function goes like this:

```
func autocompleteView(_ autocompleteView: LUAutocompleteView,
                        elementsFor text: String,
                              completion: @escaping ([String]) -> Void)
```

So far, so simple. I go into my Objective C code and call this function as usual, and the entire game looks like this once I'm finished:

```
 - (void)autocompleteView:(LUAutocompleteView * _Nonnull)autocompleteView
         elementsFor:(NSString * _Nonnull)text
         completion:(void (^ _Nonnull)(NSArray<NSString *> * _Nonnull))completion
    {

         self.currentSuggestions = [self doAPIMagic];
         completion(self.currentSuggestions);

     }
```

So far, so good. If I run this bunch of code in debug mode, it compiles and executes cleanly. Now, if I run it on Release (for example, via Hockey) the code crashes. How is that possible? Is there something I don't understand? Sadly, there's no way to provide any error messages since the crash only comes if I run it in Release Mode. Thanks in Advance!

P.S.: For reference: This is the framework I'm talking about: https://github.com/LaurentiuUngur/LUAutocompleteView

Comment: You can check this: [Swift app crashes when trying to reference Swift library libswiftCore.dylib.](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/qa/qa1886/_index.html)

Comment: Another thing to check out is the `Apple LLVM 7.0 - Code Generation, Optimization Level` option in your build settings. This will have 2 different options (by default) - one for release and one for debug. This is often the cause of such issues between debug and release. I wouldn't recommend changing it permanently, but may be worth making the release one match the debug one for testing (and then switch to the other to try to debug what the problem is)